# feature-install results in missing requirement message in karaf 4.0.7

Tags: java, osgi, karaf

This is a simple `feature.xml`(v1.4.0) and all I did was specify

```
feature:install my-feature
```

Hence the error:

> Error executing command: Unable to resolve root: missing requirement [root] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=my-feature; type=karaf.feature; version="[2.0.0,2.0.0]"; filter:="(&(osgi.identity=my-feature)(type=karaf.feature)(version>=2.0.0)(version<=2.0.0))" [caused by: Unable to resolve my-feature/2.0.0: missing requirement [my-feature/2.0.0] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=vertx-auth-common; type=osgi.bundle; version="[3.3.3,3.3.3]"; resolution:=mandatory [caused by: Unable to resolve vertx-auth-common [52](R 52.0): missing requirement [vertx-auth-common [52](R 52.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=io.vertx.core.buffer)(version>=3.3.0)(!(version>=4.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve io.vertx.core [53](R 53.0): missing requirement [io.vertx.core [53](R 53.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=io.netty.handler.codec)(version>=4.1.0)(!(version>=5.0.0)))]]]

I was under the impression that specifying my bundles in a feature and installing would pull them all into karaf.

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Since Karaf 4.0, Karaf features are validated prior installation. So one of the Imports for your own bundle can't be located in the feature you provided and also in none of which is already installed. Therefore you have this error.

Btw. regarding Karaf and vertx features, might want to take a look at the following [Project](https://github.com/ANierbeck/Karaf-Vertx) (still WIP) 
There you'll also will find a working feature descriptor for Vert.X on Karaf.

Comment: All the bundles that I need are in the feature. For e.g. : if I physically do a bundle:install for io.netty.handler.codec, then the error moves on to the next one. How do  I goes out troubleshooting this ?